# dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (tried to use disallowed plaintext auth)

Tags: centos

I have just installed Virtualmin on Centos 7.6 I am stuck-up with Dovecot POP3 Server Facing an error:

> dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (tried to use disallowed plaintext auth)

I have googled for the solution but none worked.

Comment: Can you include some screen shots of your dovecot settings or the config file? JIC You can blur out or remove sensitive information of course. I do not use Centos, however, I do have Virtualmin and Dovecot working. I am sure it is not that simple, however, without it we are flying blind. The problem may be a Centos specific problem, Who knows? Cheers!!